# using exec() to parse an import statement

Tags: python, import, exec, python-import

How do I use this format of code to find if a module exists within a python program? I need to specifically use `exec()` to parse an `import` statement.

```
def file_exists(name):
  try:
    exec()
  return True #if the file does exist
  except:
    return False

#tests
file_exists(module1) #should return true because there is a module named module1
file_exists(module2) #should return false because there is not a module named module2.
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `exec`? You can make a call to `importlib.import_module` and catch a `ModuleNotFoundError` to determine if the module exists or not

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear *why* you specifically must use `exec()` because it's a poor way of doing it — unless this is homework or something — but here's how it could be done:

```
def file_exists(name):
    try:
        exec(f'import {name}')
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

# tests
print(file_exists('sys'))      # -> True 
print(file_exists('module2'))  # -> False
```